# Does anyone use the L-Track trackball?

Tags: trackball

I've been using the Logitech Trackman Marble Mouse for years.

Now I'm looking for a trackball with a scroll wheel, larger and heavier ball, and preferably rollers instead of pins. It must be finger (not thumb) operated.

The Kensington Expert Mouse is close, but from what I've read the scroll wheel is poorly implemented. They also switched from rollers to pins.

I bought a Kensington Orbit Trackball and it's not bad but the scroll wheel is rough and the ball is the same as the marble mouse. I'm still looking for something better.

I found the [L-Trac](http://clearlysuperiortech.com/Ltracproductinfo.pdf) and it looks good but there's little info on the web.

Has anyone used it and can provide their impressions?

Or can you point out another option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about anyone else, but I love my [Expert Mouse](http://us.kensington.com/html/2200.html). Big ball, four buttons, easy scroll ring. It's also optical so no rollers to get gunked up.

Comment: I've read the scroll ring doesn't work smoothly - what do you think?
They also gave it a steep angle in the latest version that doesn't seem ergonomic - seem ok to you?
Do you use the wrist rest that comes with it?
Thanks for the feedback Josh.

Comment: Not a huge fan of the wrist rest, and the scroll ring works fine for me. I don't scroll a ton though.

Answer (score 0):

Seconding the Expert Mouse.  I ditched the wrist rest and set the whole mouse on a neoprene mouse-pad - it works better for me.  I use the scroll ring sometimes, but prefer to use the the 3-rd button X-Y scrolling (the more you displace the mouse, the faster the window scrolls in that direction).